# list of numbers - how do I find repeating patterns?

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I have a list of numbers. There are repeating patterns among a lot of noise.

sample data:

```
(1,2,50,10,100,25,12,30,20,1,20,10,100,25,12,50,30,2,10,100,25,12,50,30,30,40,20,40,1,2,50,20,50,30,30,10,100,25,12,10,100,25,12)
```

in this example, the desired pattern is `10,100,25,12`, but will be different each time.

How do I find *any* repeating pattern?

Comment: If you definition of repeating is that there are at least two occurrences then pick any number in the list that occurs at least twice and there is your repeating pattern. What I am trying to say is, you need more restrictions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A suffix tree is the most efficient solution for finding repeating substrings in a string.

Here's one example of a Python implementation: https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dyoo/python/suffix_trees/

If you don't want to bother with such an involved solution, you can simply iterate over the string, one element at a time, and remove each element if it is NOT "10" "100" "25" or "12". Eventually, you'll get to the first element that consists of the "10" "100" "25" and "12" sequence.

If your question calls for any general pattern, you most likely want to go with a suffix tree, or else you're looking at large time-complexities.

Comment: Thanks for this. It would be a general pattern, not just, 10,100,25,12 - different each time. How can I use a suffix tree in this way?

Comment: You'll have to edit the classes (the Node/Edge class, whatever they use to implement the tree). Here's an excellent visualization (the only one on the internet, by the way) of a suffix tree. You can play around with it to understand how it works, and what you need to edit.

http://suffixtree.codeplex.com/

Download the 'SuffixTreeGarden' ZIP. Open the project SuffixTreeView, and compile the project and run it. You may need to download the appropriate F# runtime - but it's a beautiful visualization/animation, very worth it. By the way, the suffix tree isn't exactly easy to implement. Good luck!

Comment: Let me know if you can't compile it, I can directly link you my compiled executable.